# What do you do if you don't want a depth buffer in your render pass sometimes?

Tags: vulkan

My question relates to any time when sometimes you're writing to an attachment, but other times you're not. So let's just say that my render pass usually writes to a depth buffer, but in some cases I don't need the depth buffer? As far as I can see there are couple of ways to handle this:

1. Disable depth buffer writing and attach a dummy image (apparently the dummy image has to be as big as the colour buffer, not sure if this is a waste of memory)
2. Create a separate render pass that only writes to the colour buffer.

In my case I want to treat the colour writing, depth writing and picking writing as separate things. Is it better to use dummy images or to have three render passes (colour, colour-depth, colour-depth-picking)? How does this apply generally? I'm guessing in the future there may be extra attachments that I may want to switch on/off.

Edit: Can you have a render pass that writes to 3 attachments, but only have 1 attachment in the framebuffer if you disable certain attachments? I'm guessing not as I've been told that you need to have images attached to each one of size at least the size of the biggest one, or the size of the framebuffer.

Comment: When would this actually come up? I can understand a scenario like rendering a UI, but that's just a subpass that doesn't use the depth attachment. I have a hard time understanding when there would be a circumstance where you need to arbitrarily turn on or off depth testing like this.

Comment: @NicolBolas I can think of a couple of cases for the depth buffer, but right now I'm trying to figure out how to optionally render into an integer picking buffer. A similar example I can think of is what if you want to do a depth-only pass? You strip out the fragment shader from the pipeline, what do you attach to the colour attachment in the framebuffer when the render pass expects a colour attachment and a depth attachment? Or do you make a separate render pass?

Comment: "*A similar example I can think of is what if you want to do a depth-only pass? You strip out the fragment shader from the pipeline*" I don't understand the question. If you've changed the pipeline... you've *changed the pipeline*. So you're using a different pipeline. Since it's a different pipeline object, it should use a different subpass of the render pass. A subpass specifically for depth-only passes, which uses no color attachments. So there's no problem. There is only a problem if you're trying to use the same pipeline in the same subpass/render pass as one with those attachments.